# How to solve Repository exception?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

The primary key in my sql table is `_id,`
but my repository works only with `Guid Id` because of this code

```
public interface IEntity<TId>
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

tried changing it to `_id` in my IEntity interface, but it doesn't recognize the primary key, also it gave me an exception here

```
public abstract class Repository<T, TPrimaryKey> : IRepository<T, TPrimaryKey> where T
     : class, IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
 {
     protected readonly DbContext Context;
     private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;

     protected Repository(DbContext context)
     {
         Context = context;
         _entitySet = Context.Set<T>();
     }
```

for example here:

```
public class Account : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid _id { get; set; }

    [Column("person_id")]
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    [Column("groupRules_id")]
    public Guid GroupRulesId { get; set; }
}
```

Exception:

> The entity type 'Address' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types

also tried adding annotation [Key], but it doesn't work

Comment: Why do you have that `interface IEntity<TId>` at all? (I consider that an anti-pattern and a bad-practice because it precludes the use of composite keys - and it imposes many other kinds of unnecessary constraints on the design of your system. Just because some classes/types just-so-happen to have some members in-common does not mean you need to codify it into an interface).

Comment: Why on earth would you name your column with an underscore prefix? Anyway, just leave it as `Id` on your entity and map the column using an attribute `[Column("_id")] public Guid Id { get; set; }`

Comment: @Dai That's actually super useful to have in EF projects. I don't see it as an antipattern at all

Comment: @DavidG I've been using EF since 2008 and while I _do_ have an empty `interface IEntity {}` for use as a generic-type-constraint with `DbSet<T>` refinement-types, I don't use it for keys/members.

Comment: @Dai I would say an empty interface (often called a marker interface) is more of an antipattern

Comment: ... which is an interesting discussion to have, Dai & DavidG, but doesn't help the OP, right?

Comment: @Fildor Don't get in the way of a good nerd-fight

Comment: @DavidG Tried         ```[Column("_id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }``` but it doesn't help

Comment: :D _"Don't get in the way of a good nerd-fight"_ Didn't mean to. Just had my share of _that_ for today i.r.l. :/

Comment: @Fildor Ooof :/ \*nerd-hug\*

Comment: *"but it doesn't help"* - tried `[Key, Column("_id")]` yet?

Comment: @BagusTesa yup, same error

Comment: @WinterWind *"The entity type `'Address'` requires a primary key to be defined."* - not sure whats wrong, on your example you give `Account` class definition but not `Address`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` to build a DB snapshot, the exception never occured again